# Eclipse/Maven showing errors on project creation

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm trying to learn something new by following a tutorial, but I can't even get started with project creation. I'm very new to Maven, so I don't know how to fix this. I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and I have Maven 3.2.5 installed on a windows 10 machine (also, JDK 1.8.0.131 is set).

The thing is, I can create a new Maven project by going to New > Other > Maven Project > Check "create simple project" > enter a Group ID, Artifact ID and click Finish. But thn I get presented with a "Setup Maven plugin connectors" dialog and the pom.xml file shows more errors.

[image: Eclipse dialog]

I've read posts of other people having this problem but they were trying to import a project, or they were using other frameworks like spring. I'm just trying to create a plain, simple Maven project from scratch.

I've also read that Maven comes bundled with Eclipse now, so I went to  Window > Preferences > Maven > Installation and saw that I had "Embedded" selected and "Workspace" showing up as "not available". So I added (not sure if did it right) my maven home directory:

[image]

I deleted the project, restarted Eclipse, then started all over. Still, nothing changed.

I also tried selecting one of the options in the "Setup Maven plugin connectors" dialog from the "Action" column, and it installed some annotations and other stuff. Still, no good.

From pom.xml I get the suggestion to install connectors, but I have no clue as to what to install.

[image]

Anything else I can try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the problem was that I had a custom settings.xml file I had inherited from a previous installation (work-related) in my .m2 folder. I removed it so now I could use the general settings file. Then I updated and cleaned the project within Eclipse and it seems to be working now.